# ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE - when taking a photo on Android 12 (S) Pixel emulator

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-12

In my app I use code to take photo from official camera2 sample https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Basic

I updated my app project from 30 SDK to 31 SDK and checked taking photos on Pixel 3 emulator with Android 12 (S) but it fails to take photos with `ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE` error

In official sample it crashes with the same error at https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2Basic/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/basic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L286

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Camera 0 error: (4) Fatal (device)
        at com.example.android.camera2.basic.fragments.CameraFragment$openCamera$2$1.onError(CameraFragment.kt:276)
```

```
E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
    android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
```

Anyone tried this sample on real device with the newest Android (12)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 12 Emulator issue.

Will be fixed with an update soon https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/432#issuecomment-952121904

Answer (score 0):

`CameraAccessException` suggests that it has no permission to access the camera device (for whatever reason). Couldn't test on Android 12 yet, as my G100 is still running Android 11.

The code you've linked most definitely doesn't match, because it `throws RuntimeException`.
In case the execution reach until there, I'd set a breakpoint and check for the `camera` varibale.

Comment: I received an answer here https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/432#issuecomment-952121904 It's emulator Android 12 issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on [CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): Error configuring streams: Function not implemented (-38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946237/cameraaccessexception-camera-error-3-error-configuring-streams-function-not?noredirect=1#comment135926067_76946237) I just change the camera to a better one and it worked as a charm (the new one was "android compatible" that was the only difference between them. that and the price)