# CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): Error configuring streams: Function not implemented (-38)

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-tv, usb-camera

I downloaded the repo for CAMERA2: https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic/tree/master but when I  run the app and clicks on any of the available cameras, the following error appears
**android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): endConfigure:510: Camera 102: Error configuring streams: Function not implemented (-38)**

I have 2 USB cameras plugged on my Android TV

Any words would be appreciated

Comment: I get the same error with a particular camera model (from Arducam). What camera are you using?

Comment: thanks @steve, I used some random cheap camera, I tried the same code with a logitech and it works as a charm. (in the specs the working camera detailed that was android compatible)

Comment: The Arducam sort of claims Android support by saying "Android compatibility: contact us for support". When I contacted them they said it's "driver-free" which is hogwash. I assume they mean the driver is in Android. Some support, eh? FYI: https://www.arducam.com/product/b0196arducam-8mp-1080p-usb-camera-module-1-4-cmos-imx219-mini-uvc-usb2-0-webcam-board-with-1-64ft-0-5m-usb-cable-for-windows-linux-android-and-mac-os/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got some kind of answer. Some cameras has the "android compatibility" in their specs. (like Logitech) those are a little more expensive but they work.
I bought a Logitech and it works as a charm.
so, do not buy the cheapest, and that's it